# Create UIViews programmatically in Objective-C and put that in a closure

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uiview, closures

In Swift I would do this to create a UIView in a kind of closure (I think this is a closure), how can I do this same exact thing in objective-C?
I don't want to set up all the variables and stuff like that in ViewDidLoad().
Thanks for your help.

```
let myView: UIView = {
    let view = UIView()
    view.layer.masksToBounds = true
    view.layer.cornerRadius = 5
    view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return view
}()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The closest you can get without doing it in `init` or `viewDidLoad` is lazy instantiation.

```
@interface SomeClass: NSObject
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIView *myView;
@end 

@implementation SomeClass

- (UIView *)myView
{
    if (!_myView) {
        _myView = [[UIView alloc] init];
        _myView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
        _myView.layer.cornerRadius = 5;
        _myView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    }

    return _myView;
}

@end
```

Comment: I showed how to instantiate an object in a block and return the object as the result of the block, but your answer is probably closer to the **real** question the OP was asking than mine. (Lazy instantiation of a property.) Voted.

Comment: How can I call it?(I am a noob in objective c)

Comment: To call it is just `self.myView`.

Answer (score 2):

You can create nearly identical code in Objective-C:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIView *myView = ^UIView*() {
        UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectZero];
        view.layer.masksToBounds = TRUE;
        view.layer.cornerRadius = 5;
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = FALSE;
        //Add constraints
        return view;
    }();
    [self.view addSubview: myView];
}
```

However, that won't create a computed variable like it does in Swift. It just defines a block and calls it in order to initialize a **local** variable.